# URL rewrite rule is not working in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .htaccess, iis

I have below condition with I suppose to redirect to google.com. Looks like it is not firing when I tried `http://dev.domain.com/iapps/ebiz`.

Is there anything wrong in the rule?

```
    <rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect With Slash" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="http://dev.domain.com/iapps/ebiz" ignoreCase="true" />
      <conditions>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://dev.domain.com/iapps/ebiz/" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect With Slash" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*?iapps/ebiz$" ignoreCase="true" />
      <conditions>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://dev.domain.com/iapps/ebiz/" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

URL matches is without protocol and domain name in condition.

Comment: but I want redirect action  "url="/iapps/ebiz/" will still work? I was testing to google.com but suppose to redirect `url="/iapps/ebiz/"`

Comment: Still the same... not firing

Comment: I am trying to add "/" after that url

Comment: Looks like something wrong... it is not working at all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75140/discussion-between-anubhava-and-james123).

Comment: If it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.